# Проблема публикации файлов по FTP (VS2019)

Tags: c#, linux, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Публикую Web проект (ASP.NET Core 2.2) на сервер Linux по FTP, публикуется без ошибок, с конфигурацией  Release + удаление существующих файлов. 
В итоге публикует какой то стартовый проект.

Публикую проект Debug+удаление существующих файлов, публикуется пустой проект, хотя на самом деле все отлажено и работает. Да даже стартовый проект так публикуется при малейших изменениях.

При публикации на локальную систему, все публикуется как надо

В чем может быть проблема в VS2019 или в FTP?

**UPD** конфиг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может вы не ту кнопку нажимаете или не там нажимаете, или у вас настройки публикации неравльные - это только вы можете понять.

Comment: @tym32167 там сложно не ту кнопку нажать кроме (Опубликовать), соединение с ФТП есть, публикация зависимая от версии, + Linux x64 и тд. если бы не публиковалось то мне бы написало, а он пишет что все ок, и ничего... Говорю же при всех тех же настройках на локалке все ок на фтп не ок

Comment: причем тут соединение, у вас вероятно с настройками какми то проблемы, если `В итоге публикует какой то стартовый проект.`

Comment: @tym32167 а на локалку нормально при тех же настройках, я же написал

Comment: ну так вы покажите эти настройки

Comment: @tym32167 загрузил скрины, все стандартно

Comment: У вас только 1 .net core проект в солюшене? ,

Comment: @tym32167 да, только 1

Comment: Тогда это реально странно, с чего бы студии публиковать стартовый проект. Есть вот [такая бажина](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/64081/ftp-publish-is-not-working-for-aspnet-core-project.html), но она вроде старая

Comment: @tym32167 может и старая, но походу так и не исправили, в итоге пришлось настраивать билд приложения прямо на целевом сервере. Как вариант упаковать приложение в докер, тоже работает нормально, правда придется заморочиться на инфраструктуру. IIS - ok, smb-шара - ok, ftp - fail =( Может у Apache есть агент для публикации, не знаю, пользуюсь nginx в режиме реверс-прокси. Еще, как вариант, проблемы с сетью, но куда конкретно смотреть не подскажу.